# how to convert GPX to Rinex format for post processing?

Tags: gps

I'm fining out the ways to achieve Post processing dgps.
I use android phone as the gps receiver.

Now, I've generated the GPX or KML files using an android app gps logger. I need to convert this into Rinex format in order to do post processing. I cudnt find any converter tool for this while searching the net.

Is there any other way to achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

The "easiest" way would be to use XSLT since the gpx and kml files are both xml.

Answer (score 0):

Impossible. RINEX requires more details than GPX.